# Regx Capturing repeating groups c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having an issue capturing a repeating group in regex, 
I have following text in log file and I want to add "\" (backslash) to '"'(semicolon) values so the Json becomes valid

So far I am able to extract the following value with regx 
***"key1":{(.*),(.*)}***

> "key1":{ "v1":"M.V. "1002 xyz" V.089E", "v2":"M.V. "tr34 abc" V.089E"
>   }

Which gives me 2 splits of

> "v1":"M.V. "1002 xyz" V.089E"
>
> "v2":"M.V. "tr34 abc" V.089E"

But since I do not know howmay key-value pairs will be inside key1's value I cannot use "key1":{(.*),(.*)} as there could potentially be a v3, v4 etc
How can I make use of repeating groups to get all the separate splits for keys inside the Json
Thanks you

Comment: Definitely not about parsing Json, Its about adding escape character inside the string, the string so happened to be Json, its  regx. I know the Json is not valid.

Comment: (Most) Regex engines do not support repeating capture groups (why? search on google). Instead, the desired approach here would be splitting. So, first, take the value between `{ }` using Regex, then simply split by coma. You will end up with all v1, v2, v3 and so on within a list, and each vX will have it's own index. Then, you can work on each separate vX key-value pairs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This is not a valid JSON, so parsing it with any JSON library will be hard - hence the OP is using Regex for this. Can you unlock this question?

Comment: @Asunez OP wrote: *How can I make use of repeating groups to get all the separate splits for keys inside the **Json***. It seems OP just didn't post all the data.

Comment: @Asunez thank you for you reply on splitting.I will try it our the Splitting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , Sorry I did not understand when you said "It seems OP just didn't post all the data" What amendments you are referring to?

Comment: I think you can try use `:` and `:{` to figure out it's a key or string or object. If it's a key add \ before ". If it's a string add \ before " which enclose the value.

Comment: Here is regex for you. Welcome :))
`"(?:[^,:][^"]+")+`
Can help you capture all real enclosing "..content.." even it includes " .
Then you just need to add \ before the start " and end " .
I never code in C#
regex: `/"(?:[^,:][^"]+")+/g`